# Finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, uncountably many $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and let $a \in A$ be a nonalgebraic element. My question is, are there uncountably many $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the element $a - \lambda$ is not a zero divisor but, at the same time, it is not invertible?

Comment: Why is there a vote to close? Is it the definition of *algebraic*?

Comment: @Stephen: Those voting to close so far have selected the following reason: "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."  The description includes this link: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/.  Further reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks! Unfortunately, it seems that the links you provide are, like the vote to close reason, somewhat generic, and do not shed light on the reasons for this particular question (of course I can guess).

Comment: Presumably it doesn't much matter if your question is reopened or not, but I would guess the reason for the hold is that you didn't specify precisely what you meant by algebraic. @JonasMeyer may be able to confirm that this was his reason for voting to close. I edited my answer to include what I think is the only other reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @Stephen Can you see some effort made by the OP in order to approach the question other that posting the question on M.SE? (After more than 3 years on M.SE you should have known that this is a strong reason for closing a question, as this site is not a problem solving machine.)

Comment: @user26857, Of course not! Is that the reason for closing? It doesn't seem as good to me as the ambiguity about *algebraic*. Browsing through your answer list, it seems to me that the same thing is true of the majority of the questions appearing on the first page (top-voted answers). And I have been here for 3 years, but quite infrequently and much less lately, so no, this is not so clear to me.

Comment: @Stephen Actually the first closing vote was mine, and I've also asked for the meaning of *algebraic* in a comment (deleted after you posted the answer) which the OP ignored. So, you can choose between the two reasons for I've voted to close the question. I'm convinced that I did a right thing. (Btw, the vote was also given after you posted the answer.)

Comment: Sure, it doesn't much matter either way! On the other hand, it seems to me that if the reason for closing is the lack of documented effort on the part of the OP, well, that criterion is not applied here very consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to interpret your question, from what I can tell. First, I will interpret *algebraic* to mean *algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$*. Then, the answer to your question is: maybe.

Here are two examples of $A$ and $a$ for which the answer is no: If $A=\mathbf{C}$ and $a=\pi$ then evidently $a-\lambda$ is invertible for all $\lambda \neq \pi$, so the condition doesn't hold. Likewise, if $A=\mathbf{C}[x]/(x^2)$ and $a=x$ then $a-\lambda$ is invertible for all $\lambda \neq 0$, so again the condition doesn't hold. Evidently something similar happens any time your algebra contains a non-trivial nilpotent.

Here is an example for which the answer is yes: If $A=\mathbf{C}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in one variable and $a=x$ then $a-\lambda$ is neither invertible nor a zero-divisor for any $\lambda \in \mathbf{C}$.

There is a second interpretation for your question (related to the Nullstellensatz) as follows: suppose by *algebraic* you mean *satisfying a polynomial equation with coefficients in $\mathbf{C}$* (obviously this condition will be most interesting when $A$ is not necessarily commutative). Then the answer to your question is yes, and in somewhat more generality. Observe that a finitely generated algebra is of at most countable dimension.

Suppose $A$ is an associative (but not necessarily commutative) $\mathbf{C}$-algebra of countable dimension over $\mathbf{C}$ and $a \in A$. If the set of complex numbers $\lambda$ with $a-\lambda$ invertible is uncountable, then the set of elements $(a-\lambda)^{-1} \in A$ must be linearly dependent, whence $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbf{C}$. It follows that for non-algebraic $a \in A$ the set of complex numbers $\lambda$ so that $a-\lambda$ is not invertible is uncountable.

Now for zero-divisors: for any $a \in A$ and $\lambda \in \mathbf{C}$, if there is non-zero $b \in A$ with $(a-\lambda)b=0$ then the $\lambda$-eigenspace for left-multiplication by $a$ is non-zero. It follows that there are at most countably many $\lambda$'s such that $a-\lambda$ is a left-zero divisor; by symmetry there are at most countably many $\lambda$'s such that $a-\lambda$ is a zero divisor.